# How to find json array length in json extractor

Tags: json, jmeter

Im using the following JSON and query to calculate the array length in the JMeter json extractor.

{
"data": {
"modal": "HJ",
"technicalid": "e492fc62-a886-67a461b76de8",
"viewModel": {
"series": [
{
"name": "H_0_G_0_R_0",
"UID": "J_0_G_0_R_0",
"description": "Test1",
"type": "series",
"groups": [
{
"name": "H_0_G_0",
"UID": "G_0_G_0",
"description": "Group 1",
"type": "group"
}
],
"postProcessing": null
}
]
},
"status": "success"
},
"success": true,
"statusCode": 200,
"errorMessage": ""
}

Here is the query.

data.Model.series[0].groups.length

This is working fine in the online jsonquerytool. When I use this query in the JMeter json extractor, it is returning null. I assume this is because it is returning an integer because other similar queries which are returning strings are working fine with json extractor . How to find the array length in JMeter json extractor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) you can provide "Match No." as `-1`:

[image]

and the number of matches will be available as `foo_matchNr` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

[image]

---

Alternative option is going for [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/) which provides [`length()` function](https://jmespath.org/proposals/functions.html#length) so you can get the size of the array as:

```
length(data.viewModel.series[0].groups)
```

or if you prefer [pipe expressions](https://jmespath.org/proposals/pipes.html)

```
data.viewModel.series[0].groups | length(@)
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to put a `.*` in the JSON path expression like `$.data.viewModel.series[0].groups.*` for `foo_matchNr` to give the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

Why JSON extractor to calculate the length? You could use a post processer. Like JSR223 post processer using groovy script.

```
import groovy.json.*

def response = prev.responseDataAsString ;
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response) ;
def sizeResultPractitioners = json.data.viewModel.series[0].groups.size();

log.info("---------->"+sizeResultPractitioners);
```

I tried with your JSON response payload and also tried with modified response payload,

[image]

With modified response payload,
[image]

[image]